# how to use jquery-1.8.2.intellisense file that comes wit nuget package manager

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012 and I want to enable jquery intellisense. Presently I am not getting intelisense for jquery. I dont know how to use jquery-1.8.2.intellisense file that comes with nuget. Any kind of help is appriciated